# Renaming the file Directory which contains Space based on CSV in Shell

Tags: shell

I need to rename the files inside the folder that has a space in it eg(Deco/main library/file1.txt )

**code:**

```
while IFS="," read orig new pat

do
    mv -v $pat$new $pat$orig

done < new.csv
```

**csv file**:

```
newname,file1.txt,Deco/main\\\ library/
```

**error**:

> mv: invalid option -- '\'

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

First:  Use quotes around the use of variables.  That means except in very rare occasions, you always should use `"$foo"` instead of `$foo` because if you are using the latter, the shell is supposed (and will) interpret spaces in the variables as word delimiters which you rarely want.  Especially in your case you do not want it.

Second:  Your CSV file seems to contain backslashes to quote the spaces.  And some additional step seems to have added another level of quotation so than now you end up with three backslashes and a space for each original space.  If this really is the case (please double check if what you wrote in your question is correct, otherwise my answer doesn't fit), you need to unquote this before you can use it.

There are security issues involved in using `eval`, so do not use it lightly (this disclaimer is necessary whenever proposing to use `eval`), but if you have trust in the input you are handling to not contain any nastinesses, then you can do this using this code:

```
while IFS="," read orig new pat
do
  eval eval mv -v "$pat$new" "$pat$orig"
done < new.csv
```

Using this, two levels of quotation are evaluated (that's what `eval` does) before the `mv` command is executed.

I strongly suggest to do a dry run by adding `echo` before the `mv` first.  Then instead of executing your commands they are merely printed first.

Comment: Thanks, Its got worked when i applied double quotes to the variables, and removed the extra backslashes in the csv file.

Comment: If an answer is helpful, please upvote (the up-triangle left to it).  If an answer solves your issue, please accept it (the check mark left to it).  Comments like "thanks" are not necessary; omitting them is not considered rude on StackOverflow  :)